# NetBeans - is it possible to return to editor/source view from history view with keyboard shortct?

Tags: netbeans

In **NetBeans (8.0)** I often jump between **History view** `View > Editors > History` and **Source view** `View > Editors > Source`.

Is there a way to close / return from history view back to source view with ***keyboard shortcut***? Only way I know is using ***3 clicks*** on really narrow main toolbar `View > Editors > History`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By commanding `Alt+V+E+S`---> you'll move to Source Section.

And,commanding `Alt+V+E+H`---> you'll to History Section.

The other option is switching between them using your `mouse` as they are pretty close or rather adjacent tabs to each other `just below the name of your program` after once opening them!

Comment: Oh my! I don't use `View > Show editor toolbar`, that's why I didn't see it...

BTW, cool shortcut, I didn't realise I can use generic ALT+whatever to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a button to click between the various views of a file if you're willing to use a pointing device.

As for keyboard shortcuts, try using CTRL-TAB. You can use the arrow keys while holding down CTRL to select which view of the file you wish to choose.